# Disabling the loading bar in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

Is it anyway to disable/hide the loading bar in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI?

The screenshot below shows what I mean by loading bar:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Is there any text with the Thermometer (that's the term in the Acrobat world for this bar)?

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea it was called Thermometer (why do people [keep renaming everything](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/125957/12359)...). Sometimes there is no text, sometimes it says "Loading image" or "Start recognition".

Comment: "Loading image" and "Start recognition" sound to me like being part of OCR processing of the document.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to turn off the OCR processing?

Comment: With my current knowledge of your workflow and environment, it is very hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Also a solution for me was:

Edit>Preferences>Categories: Reading> 
Reading Order Options > Reading Order: Use reading order in raw print stream.

Comment: Can you explain how this answer differs from the other one that has been posted?  Is this just a different way of getting into the same dialog box?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm four years late but I had the same problem, found a solution in the Adobe forums which solved the problem for me and wanted to share it: https://forums.adobe.com/message/6533136#6533136

> Accessibility preferences in Reading panel
>
> Reading Order
>
> Specifies the reading order of documents. The reading order
>   preferences also appear in the Accessibility Setup Assistant.
>
> [...]
>
> "Use Reading Order In Raw Print Stream" doesn't recognize everything
>   but as long as know that there is just plain text within a document I
>   won't care.

Open the Tools Pane (usually on the right). If the Accessibility Panel is not listed, enable it by clicking on the small "Show or hide panels"-menu and selecting it. Open the Accessibility Panel, click "Change Reading Options" and change them to "Use Reading Order In Raw Print Stream" as described in the forum post.

Et Voila: No more "Recognition"-Loading bars: Smooth scrolling.